# In gradle, can a subproject override the resolutionStrategy defined in the rootProject?

Tags: gradle

In my project, this is in the root project part:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  apply plugin: "java"
  apply plugin: "idea"
  apply plugin: "eclipse"
  apply from: "${gradleScriptDir}/ide.gradle"

  group = "org.springframework.data"

  configurations.all {

    // Hack to let Gradle pickup latest SNAPSHOTS
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

    // Force all core Spring Framework libraries into the same version
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
          details.useVersion "$springVersion"
      }
    }
...
```

In one particular subproject, I want to change the version applied and use another. I have tried putting configuration {} , configurations {}, and simply resolutionStrategy, but none of them work. Is this possible, or instead a sign that I need to move this subproject out to a different project entirely?

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
project("spring-data-rest-boot") {
    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
    description = "Spring Data REST example using Spring Boot"

    configurations {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
                details.useVersion "4.0.0.RELEASE"
            }
        }
    }
...
```

And got this: Could not find method eachDependency() for arguments [build_p7c7h594c24dhb3ll7q8nj34m$_run_closure4_closure19_closure21@3eff4d1f] on configuration ':spring-data-rest-boot:resolutionStrategy'.

This:

```
project("spring-data-rest-boot") {
    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
    description = "Spring Data REST example using Spring Boot"

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
            details.useVersion "4.0.0.RELEASE"
        }
    }
...
```

produced this: Could not find property 'resolutionStrategy' on project ':spring-data-rest-boot'.

Comment: What do you mean by "move out to a different project"? A subproject is a different project (in the same build). Do you mean "different build script"?

Comment: Also, what exactly did you try, and how exactly did it not work?

Comment: Instead of having a subfolder containing my new demo app, create an entirely separate app in another folder outside this entire project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency rules are per-configuration, and configurations are per-project. To make your new rule work, you'll have to use the same, correct syntax that you used under `allprojects`:

```
project("spring-data-rest-boot") {
    ...
    configurations.all { 
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { ... } 
    }
}
```

However, if you keep `allprojects` for the first dependency rule, you'll end up with two competing rules for `spring-date-rest-boot`, which raises the question which one will win.

If there is just a single project that needs special treatment, you could also use a conditional in the `allprojects` rule:

```
allprojects {
    ...
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
            if (project.name == "spring-data-rest-boot") {
                details.useVersion("4.0.0.RELEASE")
            } else {
               details.useVersion(springVersion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution that might work is to simply change the value of `springVersion`:

```
project("spring-data-rest-boot") {
    ...
    springVersion = "4.0.0.RELEASE"
}
```

There are even more ways to tackle this, but I hope you'll get the idea by now.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me several options to pick from.